# R and RStudio crashing when using DBI

Tags: r, postgresql, dbi

I have a PostgreSQL database on my machine that I routinely connect to through R. I have had no issues reading, writing, or appending data to the database in the past. Recently I upgraded to `R` 4.2.1 and since then any time I try to read data from the database with `DBI::dbGetQuery()` or to write data using `DBI::dbWriteTable(append = TRUE)` RStudio crashed.

Any help would be appreciated!

Here is the code I am running:

```
library(DBI)
library(RPostgreSQL)

pg <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")

db_connection <- dbConnect(pg, dbname = "williampetti", 
                         user = "williampetti", 
                         password = "",
                         host = "localhost", 
                         port = 5432)

data(mtcars)

# create a table using the mtcars dataset
# there is no issue writing to create a brand new table

DBI::dbWriteTable(db_connection
                  , name = 'mtcars_test'
                  , value = mtcars
                  , overwrite = TRUE)

# view the fields in the new table
# no error here

DBI::dbListFields(db_connection, 'mtcars_test')

# attempt to read data from the table
# this crashes RStudio, but processes fine when using R directly

DBI::dbGetQuery(db_connection
                , 'select * from mtcars_test')

# Trying to append the table results in a crash in both RStudio and R directly 

DBI::dbWriteTable(db_connection
                  , name = 'mtcars_test'
                  , value = mtcars
                  , append = TRUE)
```

My session info is below:

PostgresSQL 12
RStudio 2022.07.1 (Build 554)

```
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Monterey 12.5.1

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

Random number generation:
 RNG:     Mersenne-Twister 
 Normal:  Inversion 
 Sample:  Rounding 
 
locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RPostgres_1.4.4 DBI_1.1.3      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.9            svglite_2.1.0         lubridate_1.8.0       tidyr_1.2.0          
 [5] assertthat_0.2.1      digest_0.6.29         utf8_1.2.2            mime_0.12            
 [9] R6_2.5.1              baseballr_1.2.0       evaluate_0.15         httr_1.4.3           
[13] ggplot2_3.3.6         pillar_1.8.0          rlang_1.0.4           RPostgreSQL_0.7-3    
[17] curl_4.3.2            rstudioapi_0.13       data.table_1.14.2     blob_1.2.3           
[21] rmarkdown_2.14        urltools_1.7.3        RMySQL_0.10.23        webshot_0.5.3        
[25] readr_2.1.2           stringr_1.4.0         bit_4.0.4             RCurl_1.98-1.8       
[29] triebeard_0.3.0       munsell_0.5.0         compiler_4.2.1        janitor_2.1.0        
[33] xfun_0.31             pkgconfig_2.0.3       systemfonts_1.0.4     base64enc_0.1-3      
[37] htmltools_0.5.3       tidyselect_1.1.2      tibble_3.1.8          myDBconnections_0.1.0
[41] fansi_1.0.3           viridisLite_0.4.0     dplyr_1.0.9           tzdb_0.3.0           
[45] bitops_1.0-7          commonmark_1.8.0      grid_4.2.1            jsonlite_1.8.0       
[49] gtable_0.3.0          lifecycle_1.0.1       magrittr_2.0.3        scales_1.2.0         
[53] RcppParallel_5.1.5    cli_3.3.0             stringi_1.7.8         snakecase_0.11.0     
[57] xml2_1.3.3            logger_0.2.2          ellipsis_0.3.2        generics_0.1.3       
[61] vctrs_0.4.1           kableExtra_1.3.4      tools_4.2.1           bit64_4.0.5          
[65] emayili_0.7.10        glue_1.6.2            purrr_0.3.4           hms_1.1.1            
[69] fastmap_1.1.0         colorspace_2.0-3      bpettir_0.1.0         h2o_3.36.1.2         
[73] rvest_1.0.2           knitr_1.39
```

Comment: Please confirm if this crashes while _not_ using RStudio, just R. If it still crashes, please remove the [tag:rstudio] tag.

Comment: Other things to test to narrow down where the problem might be: (1) try `RPostgres` instead of `RPostgreSQL` (I don't know that one is better, just different); (2) Confirm the version of the postgres ODBC (OS-level) drivers, and upgrade if out-of-date.

Comment: By the same token, why do you do `library(RMySQL)` ?  We talk a lot about MCVE: Minimally Complete Verifiable Example.  Here is one write-up: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @r2evans I'll take a look at whether my drivers are out of date. Thanks.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel That was left over from a previous version of the code. I've removed.

Comment: Good. Now remove `library(tidyverse)` and work towards a _minimally_ verifiable example.  Many of us have found that doing so often helps in chasing odd behavior.

Comment: But there are no drivers. `RPostgreSQL`, which I had a hand in putting together, and `RPostgres` both use the native libs from Postgres, no OSBC anywhere. _That is a feature._

Comment: Good call, @DirkEddelbuettel, I was stretching when I suggested checking the ODBC drivers. Out of context.

Comment: `library(tidy verse)` removed.

Comment: Ok, thank you for making all these changes -- that is better.  If you still see an interaction with RStudio then ... I am very surprised because a) a lot of people use these packages _and_ b) RStudio and by now RStudio has their build well-tuned and generally no interactions between libraries they may use and which the user may load (there were some threading issues a decade, or almost, ago as I recall).  But if we did in fact crystalize that the sole difference between bug and no bug is on running inside or outside RStudio then you should maybe take to RStudio Community.